# How to store multiple instances of the same object within a single model?

Tags: python, django

Here is what my model.py looks like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owned_items = models.ForeignField("Item")

class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_description = models.TextField()
```

This is the data that I want to be stored

```
item1 = Item(item_name="keyboard", item_description="computer keyboard)
item2 = Item(item_name="monitor", item_description="used to visualize data")
```

My `person` owns both `item1` and `item2`, but I am not sure how to store them:

```
person = Person(person_name="John Smith", owned_items= ???????)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object relationships are wrong. If a person can own many items, but each item can only be owned by one person, that's a many-to-one relationship from `item` to `person`, which should be represented by a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (not `ForeignField`) field on `Item`, eg:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_description = models.TextField()
    owner = Models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

You can then set the `owner` for a given `Item` instance to a `Person` instance, or work with the `item_set` foreign key manager on a `Person` instance:

```
newperson = Person(person_name="John Smith")
newperson.save()
newmonitor = Item(item_name="monitor", item_description="used to visualize data", owner=newperson)
newmonitor.save()
# if owner is a nullable field:
newkeyboard = Item(item_name="keyboard", item_description="computer keyboard")
newkeyboard.save()
newperson.item_set.add(newkeyboard)
newperson.save()
```

If each item can be owned by multiple people, say because you're using a single `Item` record for all keyboards, that's a many-to-many relationship and should be represented with a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). Such a field can be declared on either model - in this case it would probably be more convenient to declare it on `Person`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owned_items = models.ManyToManyField("Item")
```

The docs show how to work with many-to-many fields - you generally would either create or look up an `Item` instance, than call `someperson.owned_items.add(some_item)`.